# How to convert from GMT+4 timezone into UTC

Tags: r, datetime, utc

I have a datetime column in Atlantic Daylight Time (GMT+4) and would like to convert into UTC using the below code, but I am having trouble finding the correct tzone to get the code to work (it doesn't recognise ADT or GMT+4). Please can someone help as I am going round in circles and the help pages of tzone are not providing a solution.

Example data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c("05/04/17", "05/04/17", "05/04/17", "05/04/17", 
"05/04/17", "05/04/17", "05/04/17"), Time = c(" 12:10:26", " 12:11:01", 
" 12:11:38", " 12:12:13", " 12:12:48", " 12:13:24", " 12:13:58"
)), .Names = c("Date", "Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

> df
      Date      Time
1 05/04/17  12:10:26
2 05/04/17  12:11:01
3 05/04/17  12:11:38
4 05/04/17  12:12:13
5 05/04/17  12:12:48
6 05/04/17  12:13:24
7 05/04/17  12:13:58

#Change system time to Atlantic Daylight Time (GMT+4)
  Sys.setenv(TZ = "ADT") 
  Sys.time()

#Combine date and time columns and convert into POSIXct object
  df$datetime_ADT = paste(df$Date,df$Time)
  df$datetime_ADT = dmy_hms(df$datetime_ADT)
  str(df$datetime_ADT)

  #create new column for UTC datetimes
  df$datetime_utc = df$datetime_ADT
  #transform ADT time into UTC time
  attr(df$datetime_utc, "tzone") = "UTC"
  #check timezone change worked!
  df$datetime_utc[1]
  df$datetime_ADT[1]

  #change system timezone back to default
  Sys.setenv(TZ = "")
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time, '+0400'), format = '%d/%m/%y %T %z', tz = 'UTC')`

Comment: I couldn't find the ADT which is UTC plus 4. This seems more accurate to me but I might be totally wrong `df[, DateTime := mdy_hms(paste0(Date, Time), tz = 'Canada/Atlantic') %>% with_tz("UTC")]
`. I'm using `lubridate` and `data.table` and `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

AST is actually UTC-4, and ADT is UTC-3 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Time_Zone)). If you want to convert directly, you can specify an offset when reading in the time and set the timezone to UTC:

```r
as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time, '-0300'), format = '%d/%m/%y %T %z', tz = 'UTC')
#> [1] "2017-04-05 15:10:26 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:11:01 UTC"
#> [3] "2017-04-05 15:11:38 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:12:13 UTC"
#> [5] "2017-04-05 15:12:48 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:13:24 UTC"
#> [7] "2017-04-05 15:13:58 UTC"
```

Or more robustly, pick a place from `OlsonNames()` in ADT and set the attribute:

```r
x <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format = '%d/%m/%y %T', tz = 'America/Halifax')
attr(x, 'tzone') <- 'UTC'
x
#> [1] "2017-04-05 15:10:26 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:11:01 UTC"
#> [3] "2017-04-05 15:11:38 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:12:13 UTC"
#> [5] "2017-04-05 15:12:48 UTC" "2017-04-05 15:13:24 UTC"
#> [7] "2017-04-05 15:13:58 UTC"
```

or in dplyr with lubridate,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% transmute(datetime = dmy_hms(paste(Date, Time), tz = 'America/Halifax'), 
                 datetime = with_tz(datetime, 'UTC'))
#>              datetime
#> 1 2017-04-05 15:10:26
#> 2 2017-04-05 15:11:01
#> 3 2017-04-05 15:11:38
#> 4 2017-04-05 15:12:13
#> 5 2017-04-05 15:12:48
#> 6 2017-04-05 15:13:24
#> 7 2017-04-05 15:13:58
```